# Different background pictures for each route

Tags: css, reactjs, sass

For example if page: "localhost" it's should use mainPage.png

If it's "localhost/about" it would use aboutPage.png

Not sure what is best approach because using only css would overwrite everything.

Comment: [Check this out](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Try to Import your localhost css in aboutUs css

```
@import url('localhost.css')
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use JS, but it is really recommended to use inline CSS wherever you aren't using the shared stylesheet.

Comment: I have `background` div in root component, should I restructure my code? I thought there a better way to do it.